# How to correctly add current monero-gui to debian bookworm

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, whonix

From adrelanos' github, this link:
https://github.com/adrelanos/monero-gui
does not work anymore.

It worked previously for bullseye however.

I did make some changes. the first step:
wget https://www.whonix.org/patrick.asc

doesn't work anymore, that link doesn't exist.

So I downloaded the other key:

pub   rsa4096 2014-01-16 [SC] [expires: 2026-01-23]
916B8D99C38EAF5E8ADC7A2A8D66066A2EEACCDA
uid           [ unknown] Patrick Schleizer adrelanos@kicksecure.com
uid           [ unknown] Patrick Schleizer adrelanos@riseup.net
uid           [ unknown] Patrick Schleizer adrelanos@whonix.org
sub   rsa4096 2014-01-16 [E] [expires: 2026-01-23]
sub   rsa4096 2014-01-16 [A] [expires: 2026-01-23]
sub   rsa4096 2014-01-16 [S] [expires: 2026-01-23]

and did:

sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/whonix.gpg add ~/adrelanos.asc

for step 3 I changed to:

echo "deb https://deb.whonix.org bookworm main contrib non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/whonix.list

It is on my sources.list.d

After updating, when I try to install monero-gui I get:

E: Unable to locate package monero-gui

could someone point out where I've made a mistake? should I use "buster" instead of bookworm for step 3?

Answer (score 1):

First, please see from the [README](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#installing-monero-from-a-package):

> **DISCLAIMER: These packages are not part of this repository or maintained by this project's contributors, and as such, do not go through the same review process to ensure their trustworthiness and security.**

Second, it's *far easier* (and safer) to simply download, verify and extract the [official release binaries](https://www.getmonero.org/downloads/) to somewhere in your PATH (e.g. `/usr/local/bin` or similar), than using 3rd party packages which you 1) have to hope are legit and 2) have to hope are the latest version of Monero.

It's also very easy to [build](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#compiling-monero-from-source) yourself.

So do yourself a huge favor and just use the [official releases](https://www.getmonero.org/downloads/), or build yourself.